# Database scheme for re-testing records

Tags: mysql, schema, mysql-8.0

**Goal**

Monitor records of temperatures for each room, daily.

**What I have created so far**

Firstly, this table shows the rooms and their `minimum & maximum` values of the temperatures they should meet.

```
CREATE TABLE `Rooms` (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    RoomDescription VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    MinTemperature DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    MaxTemperature DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL
);
```

Secondly, in this table - I can see the `ActualTemperature` recorded, on what `Date` and for which `RoomId`.

```
CREATE TABLE `Records` (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    DateRecorded TIMESTAMP,
    RoomId INT NOT NULL,
    ActualTemperature DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (RoomId) REFERENCES `Rooms`(Id)
);
```

And this is where I am kind of stuck.

The record that didn't meet it's `min.` or `max. temperature`, it needs to be Re-Tested until it's a `valid` value (between `min. & max. temperature`). Bearing in mind, I need to keep a hold of the failed records.

I need a way of keeping track of failed records, it's re-tested values and how many times it's been re-tested until it became a valid value. I am unsure, if it's necessarily to create a separate table? Or can I modify any of my existing tables to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to expand your `Records` table to include a field that states whether something is valid or not:

```
CREATE TABLE `Records` (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    DateRecorded TIMESTAMP,
    RoomId INT NOT NULL,
    ActualTemperature DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    IsValid BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    FOREIGN KEY (RoomId) REFERENCES `Rooms`(Id)
);
```

From here, you can use a pair of triggers that will check the validity of the temperature for the room, and set the `IsValid` value to `1` if it's valid, or `0` if it's not:

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_records_insert`;;
CREATE TRIGGER `before_records_insert`
BEFORE INSERT ON `Records`
   FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    SET new.`IsValid` = (SELECT CASE WHEN new.`ActualTemperature` BETWEEN rm.`MinTemperature` AND rm.`MaxTemperature` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsValid 
                           FROM `Rooms` rm 
                          WHERE rm.`id` = new.`RoomId`);
   END
;;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_records_update`;;
CREATE TRIGGER `before_records_update`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `Records`
   FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    SET new.`IsValid` = (SELECT CASE WHEN new.`ActualTemperature` BETWEEN rm.`MinTemperature` AND rm.`MaxTemperature` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsValid 
                           FROM `Rooms` rm 
                          WHERE rm.`id` = new.`RoomId`);
   END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Now let's test this with some dummy data. First the `Rooms`:

```
INSERT INTO `Rooms` (`RoomDescription`, `MinTemperature`, `MaxTemperature`)
VALUES ('Kitchen', 23, 29),
       ('Living Room', 21, 25),
       ('Server Closet', 15, 20);
```

Now the `Records`:

```
INSERT INTO `Records` (`DateRecorded`, `RoomId`, `ActualTemperature`)
VALUES ('2021-09-24 01:00:00', 3, 13.12),
       ('2021-09-24 01:01:00', 3, 15.44),
       ('2021-09-24 01:02:00', 3, 15.25),
       ('2021-09-24 01:03:00', 3, 17.33),
       ('2021-09-24 01:04:00', 3, 19.74),
       ('2021-09-24 01:05:00', 3, 21.31),
       ('2021-09-24 01:06:00', 3, 22.14),
       ('2021-09-24 01:07:00', 3, 21.05),
       ('2021-09-24 01:08:00', 3, 20.45),
       ('2021-09-24 01:09:00', 3, 18.91),
       ('2021-09-24 01:10:00', 3, 16.61);
```

Now let's check that everything is good:

```
SELECT * FROM `Records`;
```

Results:

| id | DateRecorded | RoomId | ActualTemperature | IsValid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-24 01:00:00 | 3 | 13.12 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-09-24 01:01:00 | 3 | 15.44 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-09-24 01:02:00 | 3 | 15.25 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-09-24 01:03:00 | 3 | 17.33 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-09-24 01:04:00 | 3 | 19.74 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-09-24 01:05:00 | 3 | 21.31 | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-09-24 01:06:00 | 3 | 22.14 | 0 |
| 8 | 2021-09-24 01:07:00 | 3 | 21.05 | 0 |
| 9 | 2021-09-24 01:08:00 | 3 | 20.45 | 0 |
| 10 | 2021-09-24 01:09:00 | 3 | 18.91 | 1 |
| 11 | 2021-09-24 01:10:00 | 3 | 16.61 | 1 |

Looking back at the core of your question:

> I need a way of keeping track of failed records, it's re-tested values and how many times it's been re-tested until it became a valid value.

You can now do all of this thanks to a single additional field and a pair of triggers.

##### Some Items to Note:

- the `IsValid` field cannot be directly manipulated with an INSERT or UPDATE. The triggers, as they're written, will always override whatever value is passed in `IsValid`
- the `IsValid` field will not auto-update if the `MinTemperature` or `MaxTemperature` values are changed in the future for seasonal variations